# Zend Studio Android Native Application

Tags: php, android, eclipse, adt, zend-studio

I have installed Zend Studio, downloaded and updated ADT. All seems to work ok to the point where I want to Create Android Application. The folder for the android app is created, but there are only 2 files inside:

```
.project
project.properties
```

I am not sure what causes this, as when I try to generate native app for iOS or Windows Phone it seems to generate all the files to run the app.

Have anyone came across this problem?

Thanks

Comment: anyone? spent all night finding out what's wrong, but no success

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem.. I have updated my zend and android sdk.. and now problem is solved.